# jquery draggable and droppable swap places loses functionality on first drop

Tags: jquery, draggable, swap, droppable

I have a grid of 9 squares and i need 2 squares to swap places on each drag/drop (this is why i cannot use "sortable").
I can get to the point where i can drag/drop each square only once - after they have been dropped they lose functionality... How can I make them keep this drag/drop functionality after the first drop?
Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skunksts/CrwcL/19/)

HTML

```
<div id="grid">
    <div class="block one"></div>
    <div class="block two"></div>
    <div class="block three"></div>

    <div class="block four"></div>
    <div class="block five"></div>
    <div class="block six"></div>

    <div class="block seven"></div>
    <div class="block eight"></div>
    <div class="block nine"></div>    
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".block").draggable({
        helper:"clone"
    })

    $(".block").droppable({
        drop: function(ev, ui) {
            $(ui.draggable).clone().replaceAll(this);
            $(this).replaceAll(ui.draggable);
        }
    })
})
```

CSS

```
.block.one { background-color: blue; float:left;}
.block.two { background-color: red; float:left;}
.block.three { background-color: green; float:left;}

.block.four { background-color: yellow; float:left;}
.block.five { background-color: pink; float:left;}
.block.six { background-color: black; float:left;}

.block.seven { background-color: grey; float:left;}
.block.eight { background-color: brown; float:left;}
.block.nine { background-color: orange; float:left;}

.block { 
    height: 40px; 
    width: 40px;
}
#grid {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the event again after you have dropped the object for the first time. e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    makeDraggable();
    function makeDraggable() {
        $(".block").draggable({
            helper: "clone"
        })
        $(".block").droppable({
            drop: function (ev, ui) {
                $(ui.draggable).clone().replaceAll(this);
                $(this).replaceAll(ui.draggable);
                makeDraggable();
            }

        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will help you.

```
 <script>  $(function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();  });  </script>

<ul id="sortable">  <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
 <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
 <li class="ui-state-default">4</li></ul>
```

Sortable grid also swaps component. Thanks.
[jquery ui sortable grid](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid)